# Copy a file from Windows machine to linux

Tags: windows, linux, file-transfer, scp

From remote Linux server I used "scp -r" the reverse function to copy file from my Windows machine to remote Linux machine. I used proper command for scp. It is saying "connection refused to port no 22." I am unable to copy file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not provide a scp server in its default configuration; you have to create a share (see [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol) under Windows and then access it from Linux using [samba](http://www.samba.org/).

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186944/how-to-copy-file-from-linux-to-windows-server-using-c) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186944/how-to-copy-file-from-linux-to-windows-server-using-c/187185#187185) for some more details.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. btw Is there any other way to do it? Because I don't want to install Filezilla or any other utility.

Comment: Most Linux systems have samba preinstalled...

Comment: ... and no, I can't think of another way for Windows to give away files without installing something on the windows box.

Answer (score 0):

Windows generally does not come with a ssh server. Either install a SSH server on the Windows machine, or use Windows's SMB protocol instead, or initiate the copy from the Windows side.

Comment: you mean using ftp from Windows machine?

Comment: I mean using winscp or similar from the windows machine

Comment: Ok. I'll first try that SMB thing. Thanks btw.